# Get multiple selected values of Jquery's Select2 from code behind using asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I'm combining Select2 with asp.net code behind to get the values. And now I want to get all the selected values using code behind too. But I can't get it to work. Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Multiple</label>
   <select class="form-control select2" id="ddLokasi" multiple="true" 
           runat="server" data-placeholder="Pilih Lokasi" style="width:100%;">
  </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, I manage to get the Select2 working on my web.
Here's the screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSccJ.jpg
(sorry I can't embbed the image)

Now I want to get all the values that I already selected into an array. How to do this in code behind using asp.net VB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this in your code-behind:

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To ddLokasi.Items.Count
            If (ddLokasi.Items(i).Selected)
                //Get values
                //ddLokasi.Items(i).Value
            End If
    Next
```

**UPDATE**

```
Dim listOfValues AS List(Of String) = new List(Of String)
        For Each item As ListItem In ddLokasi.Items
            If item.Selected Then
                listOfValues.Add(item.Value)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: your code not working. I can't get the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery's `val()` function to get the selected values [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Select2 will serialize the selected options into an array, where the keys in the array are the selected values.

You are more than welcome to see a simpe example here: http://jsfiddle.net/42o2a37f/1/

When you have this array on the client side, you can use any way of data submitting to pass this array to the server side.

Comment: Your code works too. but I'm trying to do this from code behind. Thank you for your response. :)